Using JCSMP API and Solace SCSt Binder at the same time
Due to some historical reason, in the same app, we are using JCSMP API for some old code while new code are using Solace SCSt Binder. They are receiving/sending different messages from/to different topic/queue.
Is there any concern if we use both in the same app?

The Solace SCSt Binder has a dependency on Solace JCMSP API.
You didn't clearly mentioned if JCSMP client and Solace SCSt Binder are sharing the same session? And what is the version of JCMSP and Solace SCSt Binder being used ?
Assuming that the JCSMP session is not shared, you should not worry.

This is better as a comment than an answer.
